# BillingClient and BillingClientWrapper - circular dependency injection

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-billing, dagger-hilt

I have a situation where my `BillingDataSource` aka `BillingClientWrapper` needs a singleton `BillingClient` object, but creating the `BillingClient` object can't be completed without a listener that's in the `BillingDataSource`:

```
class BillingDataSource(private val client: BillingClient) {
    private val _purchases = MutableStateFlow<List<Purchase>?>(mutableListOf())
    val purchases = _purchases.asStateFlow()

    val PURCHASES_UPDATED_LISTENER = PurchasesUpdatedListener { result, purchases ->
        _purchases.value = purchases
    }
}
```

And the dependency injection:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideBillingClient(
    @ApplicationContext context: Context,
    wrapper: BillingDataSource
) : BillingClient {
    return BillingClient.newBuilder(context)
        .setListener(wrapper.PURCHASES_UPDATED_LISTENER)
        .enablePendingPurchases()
        .build()
}

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideBillingDataSource(
    client: BillingClient
) : BillingDataSource = BillingDataSource(client)
```

The `.setListener` requirement when constructing the `BillingClient` is turning out to be a real headache. Of course, I can break the circular dependency by putting the listener outside of the `BillingDataSource`, but then I'd lose access to members (like `_purchases`) inside of `BillingDataSource`, and that's hardly ideal.

How do I solve this?

Comment: The best way is to register the listener *after* both objects have been created. Give `BillingClient` some kind of `init` method that creates and registers the listener.

Comment: @Jorn, I mentioned both objects need each other to be created successfully. In any case, I'd be unable to register the listener after the `.build()` call.

Comment: Right, and my advice is to *break* that dependency so that you can do your initialization properly without needing a circular dependency. If you currently need that listener in the constructor, you are probably doing too much work in that constructor anyway.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention the `BillingClient` is not a class under my control (it's part of the Billing Library provided by Google). So it's only the `BillingDataSource` I'm able to modify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract purchase listener (and possibly  some other related methods and properties) to a separate class or object.

```
// instead of dependency injection 
// you can use object here for PurchaseListener
@Singleton 
class PurchaseListener @Inject constructor(){
    private val _purchases = MutableStateFlow<List<Purchase>?>(mutableListOf())
    val purchases = _purchases.asStateFlow()

    val callback = PurchasesUpdatedListener { result, purchases ->
        _purchases.value = purchases
    }
}
@Singleton
class BillingDataSource @Inject constructor(
             private val client: BillingClient, 
             val purchaseListener: PurchaseListener)

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideBillingClient(
    @ApplicationContext context: Context,
    purchaseListener: PurchaseListener
) : BillingClient {
    return BillingClient.newBuilder(context)
        .setListener(purchaseListener)
        .enablePendingPurchases()
        .build()
}

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideBillingDataSource(
    client: BillingClient,
    purchaseListener: PurchaseListener
) : BillingDataSource = BillingDataSource(client, purchaseListener)
```

Comment: And what about a situation where the `PurchaseListener` also needs a `BillingClient`? Same dependency cycle problem. Tricky!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are creating a wrapper anyway, it makes sense to have the `BillingClient` as an *internal* dependency to the `BillingDataSource`. Then the `BillingDataSource` becomes the only way for the rest of the application to interact with it:

```
class BillingDataSource(@ApplicationContext context: Context) {
    private val _purchases = MutableStateFlow<List<Purchase>?>(mutableListOf())
    val purchases = _purchases.asStateFlow()

    private val client = BillingClient.newBuilder(context)
        .setListener { result, purchases ->
            _purchases.value = purchases
        }
        .enablePendingPurchases()
        .build()

    // expose other interactions with client here
}
```

Generally it's not a good idea to create dependencies inside your constructor, but in this case it doesn't break testability, since all mocking or stubbing can be done on the `BillingDataSource` level.

Comment: Yes, this is actually how it's done in the official docs. But they're not using Hilt in the docs so I was hoping to get a cleaner approach here. If nothing else, I'll end up settling for this.

Comment: This is only less clean if you plan on using the BillingService elsewhere. Which, if I understand correctly, you don't.